# Injectivity of measures in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, set-theory

#### Statement

Suppose that $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mathcal{A}$ being a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, $0<|X|< \infty$ (i.e., the set $X$ is finite and non-empty) and $\mu(X)>0$.

Then, $\mu$ is injective $\iff$ $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset, X\}.$

#### Proof:

Proof of "$\Leftarrow$": Suppose that $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset, X\}$. Trivially, $\mu(\emptyset)=0=\mu(\emptyset) \Rightarrow \emptyset = \emptyset$. Similarly with $X$. Since $\mu(X) > 0 = \mu(\emptyset)$ and $X$ is not empty, implies that $X \ne \emptyset$.

Proof of "$\Rightarrow$": By way of contradiction, suppose that $\mu$ is injective and $|\mathcal{A}| \ge 3$. Since $X$ is finite, $|X| = n$, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So, if $\emptyset \ne A \ne X$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, then $A^c := X - A \in \mathcal{A}$. Hence, $\mathcal{A}$ has at least $4$ elements. (Notice as well that $\mathcal{A}$ is at most $2^{|X|} = 2^n$. Hence, $\mathcal{A}$ is finite, but this not so important).

We can find a counterexample. Take any finite non-empty $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$). However, $\mu(B) = 0$ because $B$ has $0$ "volume" in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence, $\mu$ is not injective. But we assumed that $\mu$ was injective. Therefore, a contradiction.

#### Question

Is this proof correct and valid? If not, can somebody find a counterexample of the proof stated above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counter example.

Consider $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathcal{A} = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$. This is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Now define $\mu(A) = |A|$. This is injective.

---

The issue in your proof is that you can't prove the $\Rightarrow$ direction using an example.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I think any finite sigma algebra we can define an injective measure. Definitely true for any sigma algebra for which the inclusion map is a linear ordering